# Discord.py how to mention someone that's mentioned in the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Iv created these code here that when someone rights "send @user to court" it will say "sending @user to court" but it doesn't work here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            if re.search("^send.*court$", messageContent):
                user_id = message.mentions[0].id
                user = self.get_user(user_id)
                await message.channel.send("sending", user, "to court!")

client = MyClient()
client.run('My secret token')
```

Comment: Does it bring up any error messages, or it just doesn’t do anything?

Comment: Please also search by yourself e.g. in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) or just in the internet or ask all your questions in one as this is now the second question I see from you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a user object. To send a mention you have to do `"<@{userid}"` to mention

Here is what you need to do

```py
await message.channel.send(
                    f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
                )
```

Comment: Easier way would be `f"sending {message.mentions[0].mention} to court!"`

Answer (score 0):

Firstival you cant use `await message.channel.send("sending", user, "to court!")` because you wanted to pass 3 arguments when it takes 1 you just have to format the string. Secondly you don't have to get id of the user and then get user object with `get_user(id)` because you already have this user object in `message.mentions[0]` here is the final sample:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import re

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Logged on as", self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            if re.search("^send.*court$", messageContent):
                await message.channel.send(
                    f"sending {message.mentions[0].name} to court!"
                )


client = MyClient()
client.run("secret token")
```

Comment: it worked but not eacsaclly what i was looking for